# RestSharp serialization ignore ElementName value

Tags: .net, xmlserializer, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to make some REST calls. I defined the XmlElement ElementName parameter expecting to XmlSerializer use it, but it didn't happen.

```
public class A {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

The RestSharp request was with `<Id>123</Id>` instead of `<id>123</id>`.

```
var request = new RestRequest("/a.xml", Method.POST);
request.AddObject(A_obj); // A_obj is a instance of A
RestResponse<A> response = (RestResponse<A>)client.Execute<A>(request);
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestSharp ignores the `XmlElement` annotation. Use `SerializeAs` instead.

```
[SerializeAs(Name = "id")]
public int? Id { get; set; }
```